# Не получается запушить проект на гит с помощью терминала в Intellij IDEa. При этом команды внутри работают

Tags: git, intellij-idea, github, git-push

До этого всегда работал с гитом с помощью кнопок внутри Intellij IDEa. Когда решил попробовать сделать это с помощью команд в терминале (терминал внутри Идеи, который) Возникает ошибка

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

Так во всех моих репозиториях. Пробовал удалять и создавать пользователя, генерировать новый ключ доступа. Ничего не помогает.

Comment: Разделим проблемы на два куска. Вначале выполните команду `ssh -T git@github.com`. Вы должны увидеть радостное сообщение в стиле "hi sun_say. You've successfully authenticated,...". И там должно быть Ваше имя. Если же там что то другое - разбирайтесь с приватным ключом. Если получаете ошибку - сертификат не на месте/его нет

Comment: Получаю вот такое: Hi ...! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Comment: значит с ключами все ок. Теперь нужно видимо просто зайти в папку проекта и там попробовать `git status` (если отработала неверно - В каталоге нет репозитория) и потом `git remote show origin` (покажет куда привязано). И если все ок, можно пробовать git fetch - должна отработать без ошибок (она подтянет свеженькое, но не будет делать мердж, как pull